# Transfer wiki between different MediaWiki versions manually by copying files

Tags: backup, mediawiki, data-transfer

I am using https://bitnami.com/stack/mediawiki which "one-click installs" a mediawiki stack on my MacBook. This means I can point my browser to `http://localhost:8080/mediawiki/Main_Page` and create my wiki from that page (which I did, putting several months of neuroscience research work into this wiki).

I upgraded Mavericks -> Yosemite, and it no longer worked.

Bitnami fixed their stack; upgrading /Applications/mediawiki-1.23.3-0 -> /Applications/mediawiki-1.23.6-0 gives me a fresh Wiki.

But how to transfer all my old wiki across?

This is what the filesystems look like:

```
pi@piBookAir.local ~ /etc:
 ⤐  ls /Applications/mediawiki-1.23.3-0/
README.txt  apps        common      img     manager-osx.app php     scripts     uninstall.app
apache2     changelog.txt   ctlscript.sh    licenses    mysql       properties.ini  sqlite      use_mediawiki
```

(mediawiki-1.23.6-0 has identical structure)

I attempt to find where my user data is being kept:

```
pi@piBookAir.local ~ /etc:
 ⤐  sudo find /Applications/ -iname "*dendrite*"
/Applications//mediawiki-1.23.3-0/apps/mediawiki/htdocs/images/1/1d/2014_--_Regulatory_mechanisms_underlying_the_differential_growth_of_dendrites_and_axons.pdf
/Applications//mediawiki-1.23.3-0/apps/mediawiki/htdocs/images/f/f0/2002_--_Axon-_or_dendrite-predominant_outgrowth_induced_by_constituents_from_Ashwagandha.pdf
```

ok, that is finding a couple of PDF-s I added into the wiki as resources.

So I've attempted to overwrite:

```
mediawiki-1.23.6-0//apps/mediawiki/htdocs/*
```

with:

```
mediawiki-1.23.3-0//apps/mediawiki/htdocs/*
```

And making the following modifications to mediawiki-1.23.6-0//apps/mediawiki/htdocs/LocalSettings.php :

```
## Database settings (old x.3 version)
$wgDBtype           = "mysql";
$wgDBserver         = "localhost";
$wgDBname           = "bitnami_mediawiki";
$wgDBuser           = "bitnami";
$wgDBpassword       = "d77297bcc6";

## (new x.6 version):
## $wgDBtype           = "mysql";
## $wgDBserver         = "localhost:3306";
## $wgDBname           = "bitnami_mediawiki";
## $wgDBuser           = "bitnami";
## $wgDBpassword       = "ed5e8d6e1c";
```

i.e. Using the old settings
Also replacing "1.23.3" -> "1.23.6" everywhere.

However, this doesn't work. If I keep the new password it does produce a standard empty wiki page. With the old password no page loads, there is an error.

I also tried posting on the Bitnami forum: https://community.bitnami.com/t/transfer-wiki-from-1-23-3-to-1-23-5/26629 but can't see how to implement the reply.

How can I transfer my wiki, short of having to reinstall Mavericks + mediawiki-1.23.3-0, make a backup of the wiki, and then upgrade again to Yosemite + mediawiki-1.23.6-0 and restore from this backup?

EDIT: here is the complete 1.23.3 file structure (that somehow contains my original wiki data: http://www.pasteall.org/55429)

Comment: http://subsurfwiki.org/wiki/Upgrading_MediaWiki <-- this helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways:

1. Dump your DB from the old version and import to the new DB that you'll be using.

   mysqldump -h hostname -u userid --password --default-character-set=whatever dbname > backup.sql
2. Export your Wiki to XML and then import it.

"To create an XML dump, use the command-line tool dumpBackup.php, located in the maintenance directory of your MediaWiki installation. See Manual:dumpBackup.php for more details."

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:DumpBackup.php

Comment: Upgrading does *not* involve doing XML export, which is hell slow.

Comment: This is what I did in the end. However I had to revert my OS in order to get the stack running (which includes the SQL server). I had to (1) SQL export the DB, (2) copy across the /images/ folder, as other saved files like PDFs get stored in that folder.

Answer (score 3):

No, please don't overwrite the whole installation directory: mixing code of different releases is bound to cause problems, such as the blank page you get.

There are just two things you really need to "move" from one wiki to the other, database and configuration.

Assuming the new wiki is on the same host, just move your LocalSettings.php and the images/ directory from the old location to the new. Files will be in place and the new install will be able to access all your data from the same database with the correct credentials.

Then just delete the old installation directory (I assume you have made a backup before starting all this, as per [upgrading instructions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Upgrading)). Normally, one would first delete everything and put the new code in the same installation path.

Instead of keeping the same configuration, it seems you changed IP:port of the database, as well as the password, but kept the same database name. I doubt that can be right.

Comment: Thank you for picking up. Are you saying the entire database is contained within the /images/ directory? This doesn't sound very likely...

Comment: No, I'm saying that the database is not touched by the upgrade. If you're just changing directory on the same host, then the same database will be accessible to MediaWiki.

In fact, normal upgrade process is way simpler: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Upgrading

I've never used bitnami so I'm not sure why such complications were necessary.